# How to upload an image file to an API using Flutter (DIO)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have successfully uploaded an image file to an API using postman, I was able to attach file and send it to the api. But when i tried it on Flutter it got an error code 406 NOT ACCEPTABLE. Im not sure why this is happening.

this is the flutter code

formData

```
 FormData body = FormData.fromMap({
      "tenant_id": event.tenantID,
      "tenant_name": event.name,
      "phone_number": event.phone,
      "tenant_rent": event.rentPrice,
      "tenant_birthdate": event.birthDate,
      // "tenant_doc": event.image,
      "tenant_image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(event.image.path,
          filename: event.image.name),
      // "tenant_country": event.tenantCountry,
      "date": event.startingDate,
      "property_id": event.propertyID,
      "tenant_email": event.email,
      "tenant_bank_acc_no": event.bankaccNo,
    });
```

and this is the dio post

```
       static PostFormData({String? url, FormData? body}) async {
print("Start PostForm Data");
var response = await Dio().post(url!,
    data: body!,
    options: Options(headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      'Accept': '*/*',
    }));
print("End PostFormData");

return response.data;
```

}

I have printed the image.path and image.name and it seems that it is right, but I'm not sure why it is not accepted in the api

again, I have tried to uploading and attaching on Postman and it is able to upload correctly and accept the correct type but for some reason when i try to upload an image on flutter using the above code it wont work and i get the error code 406 NOT ACCEPTABLE[image]

but i'm not sure why it is not uploading correctly and not accepted in the flutter / mobile.

Comment: `have printed the image.path and image.name and it seems that it is right, ` Well post them and let us check.

Comment: `but I'm not sure why it is not accepted in the api` The received message in inconclusive. Your server should send a better error message. Maybe there is more in the logfiles. Maybe there is even an error stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the reference below for uploading photos using dio

```
Future<UploadModel> upload({required File foto}) async {
    try {
      var formData = FormData.fromMap({
        'foto': await MultipartFile.fromFile(foto.path),
      });

      var response = await Dio().postUri(
        Uri(
          scheme: "https",
          host: "localhost",
          port: 8995,
          path: "/merchant/upload_file",
        ),
        data: formData,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return UploadModel.fromJson(response.data);
      } else {
        return UploadModel(rcDesc: "kesalahan server / mobile", rc: "500");
      }
    } on DioError {
      return UploadModel(rcDesc: "TimeOut", rc: "408");
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is literally what i had already done, it doesnt work, it returns error 406 NOT ACCEPTABLE

Answer (score 0):

use "mime_type: ^1.0.0" package and try to change as follows,

```
import 'package:mime_type/mime_type.dart';
 String fileName = event.image.path.split('/').last;

      String? mimeType = mime(fileName);
      String mimee = mimeType!.split('/')[0];
      String type = mimeType.split('/')[1];

      formData = FormData.fromMap({
      
      "tenant_image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(image.path,
            filename: fileName, contentType: MediaType(mimee, type)),
    
      });
```